# How to set default mimetype for custom models in alfresco

Tags: xml, share, alfresco

Say we have a custom alfresco model named `common:faq`. It has properties `cm:name`, `common:question`, `common:answer`. How do I tell alfresco to set the default mimeype as `text/plain` for the contents created from this model?

When we create a content from this model, we see that the mimetype is set as `application/octet-stream` by default. Instead we want this to be set to `text/plain`. How to configure this?

Note: when we create a content from other content models which has a cm:content property, alfresco sets the mimetype as `text/plain` by default.

Alfresco content service version: 5.2.

Already tried things like, mentioning `<show id="mimetype"/>` in `share-config.xml`.

Comment: What do you mean by "contents created from this model"? How do you create a node? Do you use a Java or JavaScript API? Do you use some Share Action? Which? Properties, types, and aspects defined in a model have no influence on the mime type of the content property of the node.

Comment: Yeah, I agree with Lutz, that mimetype is a result of your action, you should look into that.

Comment: @lutz-horn We are using alfresco share to create content. It's basically a text content

Answer (score 0):

You can transform your document using [js api](http://docs.alfresco.com/4.1/references/API-JS-Transformation-document.html)  if transformation is available to your required **mimetype** then you can transform your document.

To check about transformation details `<host>:<port>/alfresco/s/mimetypes` .

you can tranform your document to required mimetype by using rule also